# Laravel queue email with attachment

Tags: laravel, email, email-attachments, task-queue

Hi everyone i'm just trying to queue my email with attachment in laravel project, but it does not seems to work. when i try to send an attachment without queue my mail it is working absolutely fine, but when i put my email in queue it just stop working. email is sent but attachment doesn't.

here is my code for email  in controller

```
 Mail::to($request->email)->send(new ContactUsEmail($contact_us));
```

and below code is from my mail job

```
class ContactUsEmail extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{



 use Queueable, SerializesModels;
/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected $data;
public function __construct($data)
{
    $this->data = $data;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    $extension = explode('.',$this->data->attachment)[1];
    return $this->subject($this->data->topic)->attach(public_path('/storage/attachments/contact-us/' . $this->data->attachment),
        [
            'as' => $this->data->attachment,
            'mime' => 'application/'. $extension
        ])->markdown('mail.contact-us' ,[
        'subject' => $this->data->subject,
        'name' => $this->data->name,
        'email' => $this->data->email,
        'description' => $this->data->description,

    ]);
}


}
```

please let me know if i'm doing something wrong or missing something.
i appreciate your response

Comment: `public_path` this will make the path into url (e.g. `http://localhost:8000/storage/attachment/...`) right? have you tried not using `public_path`?

Comment: @BagusTesa yes i have tried

Comment: what is the content of `$this->data->attachment`?

Comment: this is the file name in $this->data>attachment @BagusTesa

Comment: just to be sure, did you try the email on actual address (e.g. gmail)? or did you use a dummy receiver (e.g. FakeSMTP)? if its the former, a wrong mimetype can cause the attachment dropped by the receiver on some cases. your best shot to know its smtp issue or code issue, use FakeSMTP or similar tool - preferably that can run on your own machine.

Comment: it is working perfectly fine when i remove it from queue but i got issue when i put this email in queue @BagusTesa

Comment: so, when using queue only the attachment gone but mail sent?

Comment: @BagusTesa yeah exactly